# WebRTC arm64 Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webrtc, arm64

I'm trying to build a WebRTC project on xCode with an ARM64 architecture.
I have made some progress solving errors, but I'm stuck on this final one:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCVideoRenderer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in CallViewController.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCVideoRendererAdapter)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but , go to the build settings and change the build active architectures only to NO , and try ,and if you are running in simulator then change valid architecture to i386 .

I am not sure but if it will help .

cause i have gone through same problem and it was solved by this solution .

Comment: Already tried that.
We have fixed this error by copying the header files again.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @lorenzo373 which header files did you copy? I am trying to run iOS-SDK Helper of this SightCall Video API but unable to even run it.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj The header files located at: "src/talk/app/webrtc/objc/public/"

Answer (score 0):

I work with the WebRTC Cococapod. The issue is that you're trying to build and use RTCVideoRenderer on armv7. 
Add an architecture check and it will be resolved:

```
    #if arch(arm64)
        //RTCVideoRenderer
    #else
       //Other case
    #endif
```